# How to import external library in python?

Tags: python

Hie can anyone help me out with detailed process of downloading & importing an external library called PyEnchant, to check a spelling of word is valid english word or not

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks. My answer is below, and there is also another good one that you can take a peek at :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to install it with

```
pip install pyenchant
```

Simple usage Example from the docs:

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
d.check("Hello") # Returns True
d.check("Helo")  # Returns False
```

For installing pip see: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip

Answer (score 2):

The official [PyEnchant page](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html) asks these prerequisites before you install:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> To get PyEnchant up and running, you will need the following software
>   installed:
>
> ```
> Python 2.6 or later
> The enchant library, version 1.5.0 or later.
>     For Windows users, the binary installers below include a pre-built copy of enchant.
>     For Mac OSX users, the binary installers below include a pre-built copy of enchant.
> ```

For your convenience there's an exe which should be able to do the above - [Download it](http://pypi.python.org/packages/any/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.6.win32.exe).

If you want to install enchant first, and then pyenchant, then download enchant from [here](http://www.abisource.com/download/).

Pyenchant is on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/), so you should be able to

```
pip install pyenchant
```

If you don't have pip, then download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run `python get-pip.py` (this might require you to have admin privileges)

and then in your python prompt,

```
>>> import enchant
>>> help(enchant)
```

From the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/):

```
>>> import enchant
>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>> d.check("Hello")
True
>>> d.check("Helo")
False
>>> d.suggest("Helo")
['He lo', 'He-lo', 'Hello', 'Helot', 'Help', 'Halo', 'Hell', 'Held', 'Helm', 'Hero', "He'll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 10 (64 bit), Python 3.6:

First install pip:

1. copy the text in this link https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and save it to a file in your preferred folder. Call the file: "get-pip.py"
2. click on start --> type "cmd" --> right click --> open as administrator
3. `cd C:\Users\yourpath\yourfolder\`
4. `get-pip.py install`
5. if a message appears, saying to upgrade: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Second:

1. go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/
2. download `pyenchant-2.0.0-py2.py3.cp27.cp32.cp33.cp34.cp35.cp36.pp27.pp33.pp35-none-win32.whl` 3) from the command line opened as administrator: `cd C:\Users\yourpath\yourfolder\`
3. `py -3.6 -m pip install pyenchant-2.0.0-py2.py3.cp27.cp32.cp33.cp34.cp35.cp36.pp27.pp33.pp35-none-win32.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Before you can install `pyEnchant`, you must install `Enchant` from [here](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/#download).

Then, and only then, run

```
pip install pyenchant
```

in your console to be able to use `pyenchant` in your python programs.